# tkinter change stringvar in loop but no effect on window

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to change label every sec when i press the button in tk:

```
# --coding:utf-8 -----
from Tkinter import *
import time
import random

def test(a):
    begin =time.time()
    end =time.time()
    while True:
        ran = random.random()
        after = time.time()
        if(after-begin >1):
            a.set(str(ran))
            print a.get()
            begin =after
        if(after-end>10):
            a.set('over')
            break


t = Tk()
a = StringVar()
a.set('0')
b = Label(t,textvariable = a)
b.pack()
Button(t,text ='test',command = lambda x=a:test(a)).pack()


t.mainloop()
```

My console output is right,but it doesnot effect on windows.WHY?

Answer (score 0):

You can start the test() function in a separate thread, like this:

```
# --coding:utf-8 -----
from Tkinter import *
import time
import random
import threading

def startThread(a):
    threading.Thread(target=test, args=(a,)).start()

def test(a):
    begin =time.time()
    end =time.time()
    while True:
        ran = random.random()
        after = time.time()
        if(after-begin >1):
            a.set(str(ran))
            print a.get()
            begin =after
        if(after-end>10):
            a.set('over')
            break


t = Tk()
a = StringVar()
a.set('0')
b = Label(t,textvariable = a)
b.pack()
Button(t,text ='test',command = lambda x=a:startThread(a)).pack()


t.mainloop()
```

However, the thread won't end until the end of the 10 seconds, even if you close the window. You'll need to find some code for the `while` loop to check if the application is still running.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a behavior that must execute for a given time period is a frequent problem; you can tackle it with a dedicated `Waiter` class; this avoids the use of threads that are poorly supported by `tkinter`.

The following example opens a window with a label and a button. When the button is pressed, the label will update every seconds for 10 seconds, then stop.
Pressing the button again within 10 seconds has no effect; after that, it restarts the process for 10 more seconds.

```
import Tkinter as tk    # tkinter if python >= 3 

import time
import random


class Waiter(object):

    def __init__(self, waiting_time):
        """
        :param waiting_time: int, in seconds
        """
        self.waiting_time = waiting_time
        self.expiring_time = time.time() + self.waiting_time
        self.waiting = True
        # print('waiter started')

    def stop(self):
        # print('waiter stopping')
        self.expiring_time = None
        self.waiting = False

    def is_waiting(self):
        """returns True while waiting, false otherwise"""
        if time.time() > self.expiring_time:
            self.stop()
        return self.waiting


def atest():
    global waiter
    if waiter is None:
        waiter = Waiter(10)
        _atest()


def _atest():
    """ equivalent to: 
    while the waiter is waiting, 
    change the label every second),
    then destroy the waiter
    """
    global waiter
    if waiter.is_waiting():
        a.set(random.random())
        # print(time.time())
        t.after(1000, _atest)
    else:
        waiter = None


if __name__ == '__main__':

    waiter = None
    t = tk.Tk()
    a = tk.StringVar()
    a.set('0')
    tk.Label(t, textvariable=a).pack()
    tk.Button(t, text='test', command=atest).pack()

    t.mainloop()
```

#### Note:

You could make `_atest` an inner function of `atest`, but maybe it is easier to understand as it is?

using `import Tkinter as tk` instead of `from Tkinter import *` prevents cluttering the namespace, and arguably makes the code clearer.
You should probably consider using python 3.